# Alexa: Emit not working in chaining of function

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to ask a question to the user and using `AMAZON.yesIntent` and `noIntent` to capture the response. In case I get response, I am calling other function which should emit something back to user. But the emit is not being called. Code below:

```js
'use strict';

var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
var https = require('https');
var alexa;

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() {
    alexa.emit(':ask', 'my text');
  },
  'oneShotIntent': function() {
    var self = this;
    // removed the code for simplicity
    self.attributes['yes_no'] = true;
    alexa.emit(':ask', 'sample yes no question');
    })
  },
  'AMAZON.YesIntent': function () {
    if (this.attributes['yes_no']) {
      delete this.attributes['yes_no'];
      alexa.emit('oneShotSecond');
    }
  },

  'oneShotSecond': function() {
    delete this.attributes['yes_no']; // already deleted
    // removed code for simplicity
      var self = this;
    // removed code for simplicity
        console.log(info);
        if (info) {
          console.log('here in if condition');
          self.emit(':tell', 'sample text');
        } else {
          self.emit(':tell', 'sorry failed');
        }
      });
  }
};
```

The first emit is working. The `console.log` in other function are happening. But emit is failing.

No logs in cloudwatch also. It just ends after printing the `console.log` data points.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand

```
alexa.emit('oneShotSecond');
```

However I would have done it like below

```
oneShotSecond(this);
```

And then

```
'oneShotSecond': function(self) { // use self.emit}
```